# Codeigniter htaccess not redirecting to localhost/index.php/no-direct-access

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to prevent direct access to the images in a certain directory, therefore I am trying to redirect the user to another page if (s)he tries to access the images directly.

- here is the directory I want to prevent direct access:

  ```
  www.example.com/assets/images/user-uploads/image.jpg
  ```
- here is the directory I want to redirect to:

  ```
  www.example.com/no-direct-access
  ```
- and here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \/assets\/images\/user-uploads\/(.)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/no-direct-access [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I dial `www.example.com/assets/images/user-uploads/image.jpg` it gives me **404 error**.

Please help me with this.

Comment: If you don't want users to access files in a specific directory over HTTP, why expose that directory over HTTP to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct access" exactly? If you block it as you are asking then it simply won't be accessible at all from client requests (only server-side) - is that the intention? Are you not referencing these images in your client-side HTML? You are also asking about "redirecting" to `/no-direct-access`, but the directive you are using is _internally rewriting_ the request to `/index.php/no-direct-access` - are you wanting a redirect or a rewrite? Do you want the URL to change or not?

Comment: Direct as in I don't want anyone to view images lying in user-uploaded directory. if anyone dials to view any image in said directory  using url like  www.sitename.com/assets/images/user-uploads/image.jpg instead of opening the image file in browser they should be redirected to no-direct-access page. if the aforementioned image is part of any file (php or html) then it is okay to render the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Direct as in I don't want anyone to view images lying in user-uploaded directory. if anyone dials to view any image in said directory using url like [www.sitename.com/assets/images/user-uploads/image.jpg](http://www.sitename.com/assets/images/user-uploads/image.jpg) **instead of opening the image file in browser** they should be redirected to no-direct-access page. **if the aforementioned image is part of any file (php or html) then it is okay to render the image**.

The problem with your initial approach is that it will block *every* client-side request. Any images that are "part of any file (php or HTML)" will also be blocked.

To block only "direct requests" (ie. when the user types the URL directly into their browser) you can check the `Referer` HTTP request header. This is empty on direct requests and set to the *referring* URL otherwise (ie. the page on which the link was *clicked*).

However, this is unreliable. Users can configure their browser to not send a `Referer` header (so these users would be blocked). Search engine bots do not send a `Referer` header (if that is a concern). And it is trivial for a mischievous user to *fake* the `Referer` to gain access.

An additional "problem" with "redirecting" is that the user receives a 3xx HTTP response code indicating that the resource has "moved", not that is not accessible. However, with your "attempt" you are *internally rewriting* the request, so (if successful) this would return a 200 OK status (unless you manually override this).

It would be preferable to return 403 Forbidden and perhaps serve `/no-direct-access` as the custom 403 error document.

For example, try the following instead:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/no-direct-access

RewriteEngine On

# Block direct access to the "user-uploads" directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/
RewriteRule ^assets/images/user-uploads/ - [NC,F]

# CI front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Where `example.com` is your website's domain.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for this solution!